# Autocomplete that populates hidden fields based on object id

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am trying to setup a simple data entry form and I am new to JQUERY.  I need to return my database ID of the select autocompleted item in a hidden field.  I found the code online to this, but when I added multiple fields to the form, autocomplete worked by changing the reference from ID to a CLASS.  But the hidden fields did not.

I believe the issue is that I need to have the specific ID tag name to update the value for the specific hidden field.  I was thinking I could do something like get the ID of the current field that is being updated with the autocomplete...that is where I need some help.

```
$().ready(function() {

    $(".course").autocomplete("get_course_list2.php", {
            width: 360,
            matchContains: true,
            mustMatch: true,
            //minChars: 0,
            //multiple: true,
            //highlight: false,
            //multipleSeparator: ",",
            selectFirst: false
    });

    $(".course").result(function(event, data, formatted) {
            $("#course_val").val(data[1]);
    });
});
```

Here is the HTML form

```
<form autocomplete="off">
    <p>
        Course Name <label>:</label>
        <input type="text" name="course1" class="course" id="course1" />
        <input type="hidden" name="course_val1" class=".course_val" id="course_val1" />
    </p>
    <p>
        Course Name <label>:</label>
        <input type="text" name="course2" class="course" id="course2" />
        <input type="hidden" name="course_val2" class=".course_val" id="course_val2 " />
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I would appreciate any help that you could provide.

Thanks
jlimited

Comment: What does the server's return object look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution that I found else where.

```
$(".course").result(function(event, data, formatted) {
        $( "#"+$(this).attr("id").replace("course","course_val" )).val(data[1]);
});
```